# fstrim: /: FITRIM ioctl failed: Structure needs cleaning

Tags: linux, ssd, nvme, fstrim

On my Debian sid with custom 5.17.0-rc1 kernel
installed on my new (< 1 month) SSD nvme WD SN850
my root partition is formatted as f2fs(v 1.14)

I get `fstrim: /: FITRIM ioctl failed: Structure needs cleaning`

fsck is OK no problems found and OS is running without problems

```
sudo fsck.f2fs /dev/nvme0n1p2
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 976566287 (476839 MB)
Info: MKFS version
  "Linux version 5.5.0-rc6 (u1@jeanordi) (gcc version 9.2.1 20191130 (Debian 9.2.1-21)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 16 00:24:17 CET 2020"
Info: FSCK version
  from "Linux version 5.5.0-rc6 (u1@jeanordi) (gcc version 9.2.1 20191130 (Debian 9.2.1-21)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 16 00:24:17 CET 2020"
    to "Linux version 5.5.0-rc6 (u1@jeanordi) (gcc version 9.2.1 20191130 (Debian 9.2.1-21)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 16 00:24:17 CET 2020"
Info: superblock features = 0 : 
Info: superblock encrypt level = 0, salt = 00000000000000000000000000000000
Info: total FS sectors = 976566280 (476839 MB)
Info: CKPT version = 1d9fb4bd
Info: checkpoint state = 55 :  crc fsck compacted_summary unmount

[FSCK] Unreachable nat entries                        [Ok..] [0x0]
[FSCK] SIT valid block bitmap checking                [Ok..]
[FSCK] Hard link checking for regular file            [Ok..] [0xb]
[FSCK] valid_block_count matching with CP             [Ok..] [0x44993b]
[FSCK] valid_node_count matching with CP (de lookup)  [Ok..] [0x16c2c]
[FSCK] valid_node_count matching with CP (nat lookup) [Ok..] [0x16c2c]
[FSCK] valid_inode_count matched with CP              [Ok..] [0x15d7c]
[FSCK] free segment_count matched with CP             [Ok..] [0x374d7]
[FSCK] next block offset is free                      [Ok..]
[FSCK] fixing SIT types
[FSCK] other corrupted bugs                           [Ok..]

Done: 2.975766 secs
```

Comment: Does `dmesg` show anything relevant? If the file system really does need cleaning, the kernel logs should say “Found FS corruption, run fsck to fix.”

Comment: It is custom (maybe over optimised kernel :)) so
dmesg read kernel buffer failed function not implemented

Comment: Being able to read messages produced by the kernel is quite helpful IME ;-). Neither you nor anyone here is likely to figure out what’s going wrong without that.

Answer (score 3):

[The ArchWiki says about `f2fs`:](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/F2FS)

> By default, F2FS is mounted using a hybrid TRIM mode which behaves as continuous TRIM. This implementation creates asynchronous discard threads to alleviate long discarding latency among RW IOs. It keeps candidates in memory, and the thread issues them in idle time [8]. As a result of this, users wanting periodic TRIM will need to implicitly set the `nodiscard` mount option in `/etc/fstab` or pass it to `mount` if mounting manually.

In other words, unless you specified the `nodiscard` mount option for your root filesystem (in initramfs, presumably), then you will not be able to run `fstrim` on `f2fs` - and don't need to, because `f2fs` does it automatically in the background whenever the system does not have anything more important to do.

If you want to be able to use `fstrim` on `f2fs`, you'll need to use the `nodiscard` mount option, to stop the continuous background TRIM operation and allow you to do it manually with `fstrim` instead.

But the `FITRIM ioctl failed: Structure needs cleaning` result is indeed strange. [This seems to be the location in the source of `fstrim` that generates the error.](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/27a9b47c0bf595331b26c8ffa2a56b5068c44000/sys-utils/fstrim.c#L131)

The error `Structure needs cleaning` would mean the `errno` value was `EUCLEAN`. According to the [Elixir cross-referencer](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17-rc2/A/ident/EUCLEAN), it appears within the `f2fs` driver [in one spot only](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17-rc2/source/fs/f2fs/f2fs.h#L4430):

```
#define EFSCORRUPTED    EUCLEAN     /* Filesystem is corrupted */
```

Uh oh... it looks like f2fs defines `EUCLEAN` as a synonym for `EFSCORRUPTED`, which can be found [in many locations within the f2fs driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17-rc2/A/ident/EFSCORRUPTED), and is probably bad news no matter what causes it.

Your `f2fs` filesystem may be corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for info about f2fs indeed it is mounted by default with discard option ( how could even I miss it ??) still nothing on corruption side added fsck result, checked with smartmontools -> OK

Comment: F2fs is a fairly new filesystem, and it might still contain relatively easily triggerable undiscovered bugs. Such a bug might have caused filesystem corruption even though the underlying hardware is fine (as suggested by the SMART results). Also, as Stephen Kitt said, the `fsck` for f2fs is known to be less than perfect: there might be types of corruption it simply won't be able to detect yet. You might want to contact the developer of f2fs for advice.